# Arcgis python： parameter not changed leads to a dead loop

Tags: python, arcgis

**Requirement Analysis：**
   I have got a Tin/Terrain file, and I set an initial water level, the target is to calculate the volume of this place under the initial water level using the Terrain file. Comparing the volume with the actual value, I got the ideal water level.

**Tools:**
   Arcgis 10.1 (polygon volume_3D module)
   python 2.7

**code:**

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = "G:/0arcpy/hjh_split"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")

fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

inSurface = "G:/0arcpy/hjh_tin"
zField = "sswl" 
refPlane = "BELOW" 
sAreaFld = "SArea"
volFld = "Volume" 

for fc in fclist:    
    arcpy.PolygonVolume_3d(inSurface, fc, zField, refPlane, volFld, sAreaFld) 
    rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc) 
    for row in rows:
        i = row.getValue("Volume") 
        j = row.jyvol 
        while ((abs(i-j))/j>0.1) : 
            row.setValue("sswl",row.getValue("sswl")+0.01)
            rows.updateRow(row)
            arcpy.PolygonVolume_3d(inSurface, fc, zField, refPlane, volFld, sAreaFld)
        print "i="+str(i)+"-"+"sswl="+str(row.sswl)           
        print "Finished"
```

**Result:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNVNC.png)

**Question:**
The water level(sswl) is changed with plus 0.01, but The i(volume) value is not changed leading to dead loop. But why the value i = row.getValue("Volume") is not changed in the loop. What's wrong with me and how can I change the code?

Comment: better chance getting answers on this site https://geonet.esri.com/welcome

Comment: Or [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com)